# Dragging the GETPIVOTDATA formula across and change dates automatically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I need help with the below GETPIVOTDATA formula.

My formula is as follows:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Invalid (Percentage)",'Validity'!$A$11,"Submit Date",DATE(2018,10,1),"SITE","London","Is it valid?"," ")
```

Each time when I drag this formula across, date remains the same and I have to manually amend my formula to DATE(2018,10,2) if I would like to see results for the 2nd October.

As I have multiple tables and pivot tables in my report, I would like to link this formula with the above dates in my table so that each time when I drag my formula across, the date in my formula will be also automatically amended and the correct results displayed for the specific day.

My table looks as follows:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If say starting in ColumnH, *maybe* adjust DATE() to:

```
=DATE(2018,10,1+COLUMN()-8)
```

Comment: You're a star pnuts! I modified slightly your suggestion and also my formula and it picks the correct results now.

`=GETPIVOTDATA("Invalid (Percentage)",'Validity'!$A$11,"Submit Date",DATE(2018,10,1+COLUMN()-2),"SITE","London","Is it valid?"," ")`

Thanks very much for your help pnuts ;)

Comment: That's brilliant!! :)